# How to pass a filename variable to $.get() with Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have been struggling to figure out how to pass a filename variable into the $.get(....) command with highcharts. Not sure how to format the variable. Any ideas? Here is the code section with a direct input of the filename.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.get('10252017.csv', function(csv) {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'area',
                    zoomtype: 'xy',
                },
                data: {
                    csv: csv
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Outlook Solar Data'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: "datetime",
                            crosshair: true,
                },
```

Comment: Just replace your hardcoded '10252017.csv' with the variable name containing the appropriate URL. Check out https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ for more info on $.get.

Comment: Would the variable name be in quotes?